# PHP Mailer Sends Duplicate Messages

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send messages to a group of people who are stored in a mysql database with values of name and email. Right now I am just trying to send an email that says " hello $name." For some reason, everyone receives the email, but they receive all three emails each one saying "Hello (different name)"

Here is the relevant code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `emails`");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $name = $rows["name"];
        $email = $rows["email"];

        $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);

        $mail->Subject = "Your Daily Update";

        $mail->Body = "Hello $name, ";

        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get everything working? If one of the answers helped you out you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Each time through the loop you need to reset the $mail object to a new instance. Otherwise you're adding addresses over and over to the same mailing.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `emails`");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $name = $rows["name"];
        $email = $rows["email"];
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);

        $mail->Subject = "Your Daily Update";

        $mail->Body = "Hello $name, ";

        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } 
    }
```

I've added `$mail->ClearAddresses();` which will clear any previous emails that were added.

Comment: Might not hurt to `SELECT DISTINCT email, name`

Comment: You have not explained what you changed or how your change helps.

Comment: It's pretty evident by the `ClearAddresses()` function call what's being done here

Comment: @Charles I thought it was evident as well. Anyways, I've updated it.

Comment: @Sean, thank you.  No, it was not clear at all.  You changed one line of code and simply copied and pasted the original code.  That didn't make for a good answer.  In fact, you can remove *all* of that code and you'd probably come out with a better answer as a result.